# como faço para retira o sublinhado no link?

Tags: html

a{
}                                                                                                   lorem ipsum dhsjj auAHAN HSUAYh hsnsabah hsauhiHAYH HSAUHSAHSD

Answer (score 1):

só colocar assim no seu css:

```
a {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Ou colocar o nome do `id`ou `classe` da sua tag que quer tirar.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode simplesmente usar a *tag*

```
a{
 text-decoration: none;
}
```